# How to run texstudio after doing brew install?

Tags: homebrew, monterey

I am running Monterey 12.6.1 and have done

```
brew install texstudio
```

The installation went fine but I can't work out how to run it now. If I try `texstudio` from the command line it says `command not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[texstudio](https://texstudio.org) is a Homebrew Cask and the correct command line to install it is:

`brew cask --install texstudio`

(Since there is no Homebrew formula named texstudio, Homebrew smartly deduced and installed the cask for you)

TeXstudio is a GUI app and it will get installed in the `/Applications` directory. You can launch it as you will launch any GUI app (via Spotlight, Launchpad, Applications directory etc.).

The first time you launch TeXstudio, you may encounter this message:

[image: macOS app developer cannot be identified]

To work around the warning and launch the app, navigate to the `/Applications` directory, locate the app bundle, <kbd>Control</kbd> + click on the icon and select `Open` command.

[image: macOS app bundle, context menu]

You will now see the following dialogue box. Click on the **Open** button to continue launching the app.

[image: macOS app developer cannot be identified]

TeXstudio app will now launch normally. The above steps won't be required to be performed in the future and you will be able to launch the app normally this point on.

**P.S.**: If you are looking for a command line to launch the app, you can use the following:

`open -a texstudio`